# 'merge' 2 mysql queries

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries that I would like to turn into one.

1st:

```
        SELECT 
        poll_questions.id,
        poll_questions.question,
        poll_questions.qmore,
        poll_questions.total_votes,
        poll_questions.active,
        poll_questions.created_at,
        poll_answers.answer,
        poll_answers.votes,
        poll_answers.id AS answer_id,
        poll_photos.photo_name_a,
        users.username

        FROM poll_questions 

        LEFT JOIN (poll_answers, poll_photos)  
            ON (poll_answers.question_id = poll_questions.id AND
                poll_photos.question_id = poll_questions.id
                )
        LEFT JOIN users ON poll_questions.author = users.id 

        WHERE poll_questions.active = 1 

        ORDER BY poll_questions.created_at DESC 

        LIMIT {$per_page} OFFSET {$offset}
```

2nd:

```
SELECT vote_history_raw.vote
FROM vote_history_raw
WHERE vote_history_raw.user_id = {$user_id}
```

note that user in the first query is the author and on the second query he's the voter.

thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by "merge" or "turn into one"? Are you trying to JOIN them? UNION them? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Currently the output looks like this:

Comment: Currently the output looks like this: 

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 97 [question] => What time is it? [qmore] => some more text [total_votes] => 2 [active] => 1 [created_at] => 2012-08-27 10:05:48 [answer] => 8 [votes] => 1 [answer_id] => 85 [photo_name_a] => 97_a.jpg [username] => joes ) 
  [1] => Array ( [id] => 98 [question] => What day is it? [qmore] => some more text1 [total_votes] => 4 [active] => 1 [created_at] => 2012-08-27 10:06:48 [answer] => sunday [votes] => 1 [answer_id] => 86 [photo_name_a] => 98_a.jpg [username] => joes )
I want to add a vote if the user voted to each q array

Comment: if the user didn't vote for that particular q's then the [vote] can be empty

Comment: @joes_nator: You can edit your question via [http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12268286/edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12268286/edit).

Comment: Also, by "output" we mean something SQL-y, not something PHP-y. It should look like a table, not like an associative-array literal.